# Sylow-Subgroups and arbitrary groups where their order contains the same prime-power.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $|G| = p^k m$ with $p$ and $m$ being coprime. Then it is well known that there exists a subgroup $S$ of $G$ with $|S| = p^k$, the so called Sylow-$p$-subgroups. Now let $U \le G$
be some subgroup of $G$ with $|U| = p^k \cdot n$, then does there exists some Sylow-$p$-subgroup such that $S \le U$?

Comment: Use Sylow's theorem on $U$. A Sylow subgroup of $U$ needn't be a Sylow subgroup of $G$.

Comment: You mean a Sylow subgroup of $U$ must be some of $G$.

Comment: Not necessarily, but since you assumed $\nu_p(|U|)=\nu_p(|G|)$ the answer is yes in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the exponent of $p$ is the same in $|U|$ and $|G|$, a $p$-Sylow of $U$ is in particular a $p$-sylow for $G$, and so the answer is yes